# How do I return the correct variable from this function?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to print out a star rating from a database. The rating for this hotel is currently set to 5. This is my code:

```
<?php 
    function star_rating($stars) {
        echo "star rating is $stars";
    }
?>
```

and then in the place where I want to print the star rating

```
<?php star_rating(print $row['Rating']); ?>
```

I want it to print out 'star rating is 5' but it keeps printing out '5star rating is 1'

It is definitely connected to the database correctly because when i change the star rating in the database, the first number changes accordingly.

Sorry if this is really silly, I'm new to PHP! Thanks in advance for any help given.

Comment: remove print from `print $row['Rating']`

Comment: thats so helpful thanks, i cant give you credit as you have only commented and not officially 'answered' !

Comment: if you answer i will vote your answer is what i mean!

Comment: It would only be an answer (in my book) if I wrote a (long) explaination why this is the case - didn't feel like it -> comment ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print` always return 1, so in your code, the value of `print $row['Rating']` is one. It's look like calling function like this : star_rating(1);

Also print send variable to output, in your case it will print `5` and send `1` to function, and in your function the output is `star rating is 1` and so on you will see `5star rating is 1` in output.

For this problem you just need remove `print`.

`<?php star_rating($row['Rating']); ?>`

Answer (score 1):

You are already outputting the data from within the function (using echo) so there is no requirement to use print.

Change:

```
<?php star_rating(print $row['Rating']); ?>
```

To:

```
<?php star_rating($row['Rating']); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Write it as

```
<?php 
function star_rating($stars) {
    return "star rating is $stars";
}
```

?>

and call it using

```
<?php echo star_rating($row['Rating']); ?>
```